# How can I build ubuntu desktop softwares?

Tags: application-development

Or what programing language should I use to develop ubuntu desktop applications?

Comment: C++ is probably the most common

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What programming languages should I learn to become an Ubuntu developer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321403/what-programming-languages-should-i-learn-to-become-an-ubuntu-developer)

Comment: python,bash,c,c++,and java are mainly used

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather broad topic. Much depends on your personal preferences and the type of the software you'are writing. My Preferences are:

1. Java - gives you binary portability to numerous platforms, rich library of ready-made frameworks, excellent memory management and many other advantages. On the downside it is rather resource hungry and has steep learning curve.
2. C++ - you can achieve highest speed with small memory footprint, however the code is subject to subtle programming errors such as memory leaks and race conditions. Also portable but with more difficulties - high degree of caution required. Again steep learning curve.
3. One of the multiple scripting languages such as Python, Java Script, PHP, Perl and so on - I personally do not like this option. At the expense of the maintainability you just get easier get-on. In my opinion it is suitable only for small & quick applications not expected to last long or gain large user-base.

This link also may help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerUsersProgramming

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go is Bash as back-end + Yad front-end. Fast and easy to learn and very high abstraction level, which makes it very suitable for beginners.

That's basically my opinion, you should avoid asking questions that trigger opinion based answers in the future.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop software, fully written in bash? Interesting... Did you write any?

Comment: I have written a piece of software that scrapes a web page for news in a certain format using `Curl`, notifies the user and displays the news in a simple Yad front-end. Basically a news integration tool.

Comment: Bash could be quite useful in writing software because it's rich of high-level tools, also piping is a really useful feature for writing good software. You'll start having problems with Bash if you want to process advanced mathematical equations in your code, then you should probably consider something like Python or some other language.

Comment: Thank you all guys! I have learned Python for a while. But I'm just a freshman.